# Is it possible to make groups mutually exclusive?

Tags: groups

If yes, how do you add those constraints?

The [docs for Groups and Tags](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.7/organising-your-data/groups-and-tags/#groups-vs-tags) suggests that it is possible by saying that it isn't for tags.

> Tags allow multiple selections - so they may not be appropriate for mutually exclusive characteristics (e.g. "Democrat", "Republican", "Green Party")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any way you can do this using Tags or Groups. The alternative would be a custom field of type radio, and then build Smart Groups off those options.

Comment: Maybe an idea to update the docs

Comment: Pls go ahead. Community projects like this benefit from people making improvements where they can see they are required.